# symfony router match url in all locales

Tags: php, symfony

**Short question:** How to validate url in all locales with Symfony router?

**Long part:**

- So, we have an specific dynamic route eg: en.web.site/{dynamic_user_name}
- Site has many languages eg: en.web.site/, de.web.site/, ru.web.site/
- Not all dynamic names are allowed eg: en.web.site/login

And we need to implement a *dynamic_user_name* part validation. Best way will be like

```
$router = $container->get('router');
$result = $router->getMatcher()->match('/'.$dynamic_user_name);
```

But, symfony router-matcher has only one locale inside.
And now i need do this with a hack like:

```
$router = $container->get('router.en');
$result = $router->getMatcher()->match('/'.$dynamic_user_name);
....
all N locales
....
$router = $container->get('router.ru');
$result = $router->getMatcher()->match('/'.$dynamic_user_name);
```

How to do this validation without instanting all routers with their locales?

Comment: is this in a test or in some controller code or ... ???

Comment: why would you use a routing scheme, where dynamic urls can collide with static urls?! especially, if you have an existing username, and then add a static route later that collides with it. I mean, it really is prone to breaking in the future.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#the-locale-and-the-url

Comment: @jakumi this will be admin side service for new users /// why would you use a routing scheme, where dynamic urls can collide with static urls /// it is prehistorycal legacy feature :D our clients need this

Comment: @DanCostinel unfortunately *->match()* `public function match($pathinfo); ` has only one parameter. It would be very good to have second param `array $parameters` where i cant put a locale.

Comment: I think the proper way to do this is to create `Request` objects with the proper hostnames and stuff (I don't *exactly* know what server parameters may be used for this) and maybe even modify the router's `RequestContext` to match the hostname, and then use the `matchRequest` method. But that's probably more extensive than your *hack*